# I am needing to find the second measurement in this string

Tags: excel-formula

I am needing to find the second measurement in this string only, it can be 1 character up to 5 characters to the left of the second " in the string. Here are some examples of the string: `2"BW x 1"BW` or it could me this: `2-1/2"BW x 1-1/2"BW`. I have a formula to get the data in front of the first " but am having difficulties getting the measurement in front of the second ". Here is what I am using for the first measurement: `=LEFT(D48,FIND(CHAR(34),D48)-1)`. Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This finds the second `"` and returns everthing between the `x` and the second `"`:

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH(" x ",A1)+3,FIND(CHAR(34),A1,FIND(CHAR(34),A1)+1)-(SEARCH(" x ",A1)+3))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try these:
(assuming the input value is in cell "A1" ...

First value:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(34),A1)-1)
```

Second Value:

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,FIND("x",A1)+1,FIND(CHAR(34),A1,FIND("x",A1))-FIND("x",A1)-1))
```

For the second one, I use the "x" as the starting point for searching for the 2nd string ... if that won't work consistently ... give some other examples so I can refine.